# How to calculate discount for price and clear form when radio button is changed

Tags: javascript, html

1) I am trying to calculate discount for price with this code but it does not work.

2) I want to clear form when the radio button is changed. Example the size is M and fill number in quantity input only If I change the size, the form will be clear or after amount show me If I change size, the form will be clear too.

```js
 window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', total)
    }); 

    var total = function () {
    var s = Number(document.querySelector('input[name=size]:checked').value);
    var q = Number(document.getElementById('qty').value);
    var m = document.querySelector('input[name=member]:checked').value;
    var result;
    if(s && q && m) {
        if(q >= 1) {
            if(s == 'S') {
                result = s * q;
            } else if(s == 'M') {
                result = s * q;
            } else if(s == 'L') {
                result = s * q;
            } else {
                result = s * q;
            }
            result -= m === "YES" ? result*5/100 : 0;
        } else {
            result = " ";
        }
    } else {
        result = " ";
    }
    document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = result.toFixed(2);
    }

    const clearForm = () => {
        document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
    }
```

```html
    <form id="myForm">
    <div>
        <p>Size:
            <input type="radio" name="size" id="S" value="249">S
            <input type="radio" name="size" id="M" value="269">M
            <input type="radio" name="size" id="L" value="309">L
            <input type="radio" name="size" id="XL" value="319">XL
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>Quantity:
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty">
    </p>
    <p>Member:
        <input type="radio" name="member" value="YES">YES
        <input type="radio" name="member" value="NO">NO
    </p>
    <p>Amount: $
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" readonly>
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
    <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearForm()">Reset</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you tell us the issue you face, being more specific than it "doesn't work"? From what I am reading, the line `result -= m === "YES"` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: if I click yes, I get 5% discount.

Comment: Your second point doesn't make sense. Do you understand what clearing form is? you can't change radio button and clear the form? that will clear what you just selected. Do you only want to clear the quantity input or what when you change size? Because I'm confused.

Comment: Whenever I change size, form will be clear.

Comment: Form is everything. when you say **'form will be clear'** it means that the `member` radio will clear, the `size` radio will clear, the `quantity` will clear, and the `amount` will clear. Are you not trying to say that you only want to clear the `quantity` and `amount` when `size` is changed?

Comment: Check my answer. I think that's what you're looking for because it doesn't make sense to have the `size` clear the form while you already have a `reset` button taking care of that. I think you're only trying to clear `qty` and `amount`

Comment: I'm sorry for this confusion. You're absolutely right. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your calculations are working as expected.**

You have one problem in your Code:

```
document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = result.toFixed(2); //Here with innerHTML
```

inputs cannot contain html. They can only contain a value. The property `innerHTML` is not ideal for input elements. What you are looking for is:

```
document.getElementById('amount').value = result.toFixed(2);
```

You must set the `value` of your amount, not `innerHTML`.

I have just edited your Snipped. Notice the changes I made on your code. A lot of stuff were unnecessary. Like your multiple `if` statements checking for `'S'`, `'M'` ... Because at the end they all lead to the same calculation expression.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  // clear then textboxes on Size change
  document.querySelectorAll("input[name=size]").forEach(input=>{
    input.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
      clearTextBoxes();
    });
  });
}); 

var computeTotal = () => 
{
  var s = document.querySelector('input[name=size]:checked').value;
  var q = document.getElementById('qty').value;
  var m = document.querySelector('input[name=member]:checked').value;
  var result; //initialize to empty string
  if(s && q && m && q >= 1) {
      result = s * q;
      result -= m === "YES" ? result*5/100 : 0;
  }
  
  // Change innerHTML to value
  document.getElementById('amount').value = result == undefined ? " " : result.toFixed(2);
}

var clearTextBoxes = () => {
  document.getElementById("qty").value = "";
  document.getElementById("amount").value = "";
}

const clearForm = () => {
    document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <p>Member:
        <input type="radio" name="member" value="YES">YES
        <input type="radio" name="member" value="NO">NO
    </p>
    <div>
        <p>Size:
            <input type="radio" name="size" id="S" value="249">S
            <input type="radio" name="size" id="M" value="269">M
            <input type="radio" name="size" id="L" value="309">L
            <input type="radio" name="size" id="XL" value="319">XL
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>Quantity:
        <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty">
    </p>
    <p>Amount: $
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" readonly>
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="calculate" onclick="computeTotal()">Calculate</button>
    <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearForm()">Reset</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the input fields when radio button changes. Find the working demo below

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', total)
});

var total = function() {
  var s = Number(document.querySelector('input[name=size]:checked').value);
  var q = Number(document.getElementById('qty').value);
  var m = document.querySelector('input[name=member]:checked').value;
  var result;
  if (s && q && m) {
    if (q >= 1) {
      if (s == 'S') {
        result = s * q;
      } else if (s == 'M') {
        result = s * q;
      } else if (s == 'L') {
        result = s * q;
      } else {
        result = s * q;
      }
      result -= m === "YES" ? result * 5 / 100 : 0;
    } else {
      result = " ";
    }
  } else {
    result = " ";
  }
  document.getElementById('amount').value = result.toFixed(2);
}

const clearForm = () => {
  document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
}

// Add event listener to all radio items and add the clearfields logic
var memberRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="member"]');

var sizeRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="size"]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(memberRadios, function(radio) {
  radio.addEventListener('change', clearFields);
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(sizeRadios, function(radio) {
  radio.addEventListener('change', clearFields);
});

function clearFields(event) {
  document.getElementById('qty').value = null;
  document.getElementById('amount').value = null;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <p>Member:
    <input type="radio" name="member" value="YES">YES
    <input type="radio" name="member" value="NO">NO
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>Size:
      <input type="radio" name="size" id="S" value="249">S
      <input type="radio" name="size" id="M" value="269">M
      <input type="radio" name="size" id="L" value="309">L
      <input type="radio" name="size" id="XL" value="319">XL
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>Quantity:
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty">
  </p>
  <p>Amount: $
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" readonly>
  </p>
  <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearForm()">Reset</button>
</form>
```